# How can I pass a method of an object's class as std::function?

Tags: c++, std-function

I have a function that needs to get std::function-type parameter. I also have an abstract-type pointer to an object. Is it possible to pass the method using only an object?

The function signature:

```cpp
void foo(std::function<bool(int i)>);
```

The classes sample:

```
class IBase // interface
{
public:
    virtual bool sampleMethod(int i) = 0;
};

class Child1 : public IBase // one of the classes that inherit from IBase
{
public:
    bool sampleMethod(int i) override;
};
```

So there is this pointer to an object of one of the Child classes:

```
std::unique_ptr<IBase> ptr;
```

And I want to use it to pass the sampleMethod as a parameter of foo.
Is there any way to do it using std or boost?

Comment: Easiest way is to use a capturing lambda function.

Comment: `[&](int i) { return ptr->sampleMethod(i); }`

Comment: Have you looked at the examples on cppreference? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `std::bind` and a placeholder:

```
foo (std::bind (&IBase::sampleMethod, ptr.get (), std::placeholders::_1));
```

You can also use a lambda which captures `ptr`:

```
foo ([&ptr] (int i) { return ptr->sampleMethod (i); });
```

In either case, as Yakk - Adam Nevraumont says, make sure that `ptr` outlives any references made to it, or copies made of it, in `foo`.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Eowh9OgzrqZmxjNH)

Answer (score 2):

This is C++, so you have to worry about lifetime.  Your question completely ignores lifetime; that is a bad thing.

Whenever you talk about anything in C++ you must be clear about the lifetime of everything involved.  One way to be clear about it is to talk about ownership.  Another is to say one thing is to talk about scope.

The lifetime of:

```
void foo(std::function<bool(int i)> f);
```

`f` and copies of it is not clear.  If `f` and all copies are not going to live past the exit of `foo`, that is completely different than if `f` or copies could live past the end of `foo`.

Part of this is not your fault; the C++ `std` library lacks a vocabulary type to describe "callable object with no state ownership" (a `function_ref`), so people use the value-semantics `std::function` instead.

Supposing what you really want is a `function_ref<void(int)>`, then you can just do this:

```
foo( [&](int i){ return ptr->sampleMethod(i); } );
```

and done; the scope guarantees (`ptr` outlives the call to `foo`, and `f` and its copies will not outlive `foo`) mean lifetime is accounted for.

If however that `foo` may keep a copy of `f`, you have two problems.  First, `ptr` claims **unique** ownership over the lifetime of `*ptr`; but `f` also claims ownership over the object it wants to call.

What more, `std::function` can be copied; which means either the object it invokes must be copied, or we are forced to have shared ownership.

So after `foo` does `*ptr` need to available outside?  Do copies of `*ptr` make sense, or shared ownership between the copies of `f` of `*ptr`?  More ownership questions, and the answers to them change what the right solution to your problem is.

In a more perfect world, `function`, `moveonly_function`, `function_ref` would all exist, and your choice would inform what you need here and simplify the solition.

Answer (score 1):

I started writing this based on Paul's answer:

```cpp
_window.setCursorPosCallback(std::bind(&RenderWorld::mouseCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2));
```

But clang-tidy told me to change it to this instead:

```cpp
_window.setCursorPosCallback([this](auto && x, auto && y) { 
    mouseCallback(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x), std::forward<decltype(y)>(y)); 
});
```

So that's kinda cool

Comment: Interesting, some pretty clever stuff by clang-tidy there.